# Separate DHCP scope for domain/non domain computers Windows 2008R2/2012

Tags: networking, dhcp, domain

Is there a way that DHCP role in Windows Server will be giving a different settings (in this example different primary DNS server) to computers that are a part of Windows domain, and computers that are just standalone workstations?

I think that there should be two different scopes for that, but how to make DHCP server determine what computer goes to what scope?

Answer (score 0):

You want two things on different levels.

At the lowest level there is the NIC which has a MAC. You can compare the MAC with a serial number. It does not yield any information on the computer it is in. Not if it is part of a domain; not even which OS it runs or how many other network cards are present in that computer.

This means your basic DHCP server will only know that it:

1. Got a request for network information.
2. And from who that request came (based on the MAC).

Without more information it can not do what you want.

What you can do to solve your problem is the following:

1. Create two different networks. Connect the computer on the domain to one network and the stand-alone computers to the other network. (Either full physical separation, or something more handy using a two different networks/VLAN, a router, ... )
2. You can reserve a specific IP for a specific MAC.  If you make a reservation for each MAC in the domain then you sort-of archieve what you want.

Neither of these are answers I would want to accept as 'the solution' and I hope someone has a better one.